# Multiple rows and columns in UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create my UITableViewCell like shown in attach image. How can I achieve this thing?
[image: multiple columns]

Comment: i donot want to create a custom xib file, with button, on it, I want to know a better solution, i know this is simplest and fastest solution.

Comment: Two options 1) from xib 2) create view dynamically and add in cell.

Comment: Best solution is to create a custom xib file. Why don't you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a UICustomCell.
2. Use the components shown in following image.

[image]

And all those lines in background take it as a image. And, add them as a background to your custome cell.

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom cell. In customCell do the lay out. Subclass UITableViewCell. 
.h will be

```
@interface CompanyCell : UITableViewCell
//declare lable imageViews etc
@end
```

.m will be

```
@implementation CompanyCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code for labels imageViews etc
        //add to contentview
        [self.contentView addSubview:imgV>];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In viewController.m

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
               cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cell];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   //access cell.imgV or labels and give data
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a custom `UITableViewCell` xib and then use that xib for your `UITableView`. [This](http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/03/13/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xibs-step-by-step-tutorial/) post should be helpful.

*Edit*

Since you don't want to create an xib, this will be a bit messy; but you can still create the `UITableViewCell` programmatically and add `subviews` to that cell programmatically. Then, after your cell is ready, set that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yu can use this code and add any thing you want dynamically. I am just showing you the sample code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];
}

UIImage *image_profilepic = nil;
image_profilepic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_image.png"];
cell.imageView.image = image_profilepic;

UIButton *Btnone = [[[ UIButton alloc]init]autorelease];
Btnone.frame = CGRectMake(105, 5.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f);
[cell addSubview:Btnone];

UIButton *btntwo = [[[ UIButton alloc]init]autorelease];
btntwo.frame = CGRectMake(155.0f, 5.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f);
[cell addSubview:btntwo];

UIButton *btnthree = [[[ UIButton alloc]init]autorelease];
btnthree.frame = CGRectMake(205.0f, 5.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f);
[cell addSubview:btnthree];

NSString *name = @"Name";

cell.textLabel.text = name;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
//        CFRelease(aSource);
return cell;
}
```